# Compiling x64 dll from x86 using Visual Studio 2008: unresolved external __imp_ symbols

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have compiled some external C++ code into a dll, thirdpartycode.dll, using Visual Studio 2008. The code is wrapped in extern "C".

Since I am cross compiling, creating a 64 bit dll on my 32 bit machine; I am using x64 as "Active solution platform" in the "Configuration Manager".

My thirdpartycode.dll compiles and links successfully. 
Next I want to create another dll containing code that calls the thirdpartycode.dll:
wrapper.dll.
As the name indicates it is a wrapper simplifying certain calls to a complex API inside thirdpartycode.dll.
I then plan to call wrapper.dll from a C# program.

My problem however is that when I try to link my wrapper.dll, I get unresolved symbols :-(.
For each function in thirdpartycode.dll, e.g. "func1"; I get an unresolved external symbol "__imp_func1". Using Dependency Walker I verify that thirdpartycode.dll indeeed does export "func1".

I DO list thirdpartycode.lib in "Additional dependencies". I have turned on /VERBOSE and can see that thirdpartycode.lib is searched.

If I repeat this whole process but using x86 as "Active solution platform" things works just fine!?

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Where does the __imp_ prefix come from?
It is a bit confusing, since for troubleshooting I would compare exported symbols from thirdpartycode.dll using Dependency Walker with needed symbols from wrapper.obj using dumpbin.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: What are the unresolved symbol names? Are they system functions or from 3rd party code (ie an external lib)?

Comment: They are from 3rd party code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the 3rd party code uses windows system libraries.
When I open it in Dependency Walker (depends.exe) I notice something strange: My dll is marked as 64 bit. My dll however depends on C:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll and C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll which are 32 bit! As a result Dependency Walker gives me the following errors: "Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module. Error: Modules with different CPU types were found."

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify, when you added the thirdpartycode.lib to the "Additional Dependencies" you made sure to include the path to the libs location correct? Under the "additional library directories" portion of Linker->General.

Also, if the projects are in the same solution, are you making sure that your build order is such that the thirdpartycode project is building before your code?

Comment: Yes and yes. Also from the output from the linker using /VERBOSE I can see that thirdpartycode.lib is searched.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions JMcCarty, but I think there must be something else going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing a similar problem linking to a 64-bit dll via a stub library.  It appears  for my 32-bit app linking to a 32-bit dll that declspec(dllimport) appends **imp** to the function names it looks up, but only appends _*imp* for 64-bit dlls.

For example, "function1()" would become "_*imp*_function1" and is found for my 32-bit version of the dll, but when I link the 64-bit version of the dll into my 64-bit application, I get the error:

unresolved external symbol __imp_function ...

Note the single underbar appended to __imp versus the double underbar for the 32-bit version.  When I fail to link the required library in 32-bits I get the link error:

unresolved external symbol _*imp*_function ...

I can fix the problem by just appending _ to the function name in my header (ie. _function() instead of function().  This is a kludge, but it shows that indeed the decoration is different for the 64-bit declspec(dllimport) compared to the 32-bit declspec(dllimport).

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and linking to a dll created using gcc.  I read somewhere that 64-bit dlls created by Visual Studio are decorated with single underbar, _*imp*, so perhaps the problem is that gcc consistently uses double underbars before and after, but VS expects 32-bit dlls to be decorated differently than 64-bit dlls.

I have not managed to find a description of this different on Microsofts MSDN.  Can anyone confirm there is a 64 vs 32-bit difference in how declspec(dllimport) decorates function names in Visual Studio?